# Using a global collection in a form module

Tags: vba, ms-access, collections, scope

In order to implement an undo functionality for changes in a form I try to use a "global" collection.
Thus I have at the top of the form module:

```
Option Compare Database
Public ChgeStack As collection
```

and

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Set ChgeStack = New collection
End Sub
```

However, at any moment when the form is idle, checking in the immediate window (`?ChgeStack.count`) gives an error (object required) indicating that the collection is  no longer allocated.
(breaking at the end of the form_open yields the correct count of zero, so it was allocated)
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

> *"... checking in the immediate window (`?ChgeStack.count`) gives an error (object required) indicating that the collection is no longer
>   allocated."*

No, in the Immediate window, `ChgeStack` is outside your form's context.  In that situation, `ChgeStack` is an empty variable, not the collection object in your form, and has no `.Count` method.

If you want to check the collection's count from the Immediate window, let Access know you want `ChgeStack` which is a member of your form:

```vb
? Forms("YourFormNameHere").ChgeStack.Count
```

Or you could add a break point in your form's code, trigger it, and while in Break mode try your original approach (`? ChgeStack.count`) in the Immediate window.  In that context, `ChgeStack` will be evaluated as a member of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have tried all of that, with the same result: the collection exists when checked at some breakpoint in the code, but no longer after any code has finished running (it does not seem to survive).
However, when I place the collection declarative in a straight module (instead of the form's module) **as a global** all works as I expect.
So, problem solved.
(incidentally, VBA does not accept globals in a form module… - possibly because it is in fact a class?)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest declaring your collection in a code module then it is accessible everywhere and will continue to exists beyond your form.

If being visible throughout your project is a problem then rename it so you or anyone else knows it usage.

```
Public colChgeStack_YourFormNameHere As New Collection
```